# Text Extracting: Used All Methods, Yet Stuck

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html, extract, persian

I want to extract a few text out of a webpage. I searched StackOverFlow (as well as other sites) to find a proper method. I used HTML2TEXT, BEAUTIFULSOUP, NLTK and some other manual methods to do extraction and I failed for example:

- HTML2TEXT works on offline (=saved pages) and I need to do it online.
- BS4 won't work properly on Unicode (My page is in UTF8 Persian encoding) and it won't extract the text. It also returns HTML tags\codes. I only need rendered text.
- NLTK won't work on my Persian text.
  Even while trying to open my page with urllib.request.urlopen I encounter some errors.
  So as you see I'm so much stuck after trying several methods.

Here's my target URL: http://vynylyn.yolasite.com/page2.php
I want to extract only Persian paragraphs without tags\codes.

(Note: I use Eclipse Kepler w\ Python 34 also I want to extract text then I want to do POS Tagging, Word\Sentence Tokenizing, etc on the text.)

What are my options to get this working?

Comment: If you have a library only works "offline," that's because it doesn't have any network capabilities of its own. That's OK, though, because HTML and HTTP are entirely separate technologies. Use a network library (like the one Python includes) to [download your page from the Internet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22676/33732), and then use your HTML library to process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for your second option at first. BeautifulSoup 4 should (and does) definitely [support unicode](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings) (note it's UTF-8, a global character encoding, so there's nothing Persian about it).

And yes, you will get tags, as it's an HTML page. Try searching for a unique ID, or look at the HTML structure on the page(s). For your example, look for element `main` and then content elements below that, or maybe use `div#I1_sys_txt` in that specific page. Once you have your element, you just need to call [get_text()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text).

Try this (now in Python 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = requests.get('http://vynylyn.yolasite.com/page2.php')
soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text)

tag = soup.find('div', id='I1_sys_txt')
print(tag.get_text() if tag else "<none found>")
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. It did solve the case. It returned the whole Persian Text without any damn tag just pure text. I can't vote it up now since it needs me to have 15 reputations so I just marked it as accepted.

Comment: It needs some modification to work w\ Py34: if tag: print (tag.get_text()) else: print ('None found') Your answer was Okay I just rewrite that part for people who may come to this question later. Thanks for help!

Comment: Glad it worked (yes that was python2 syntax)! So yes, you could also just use `print(tag.get_text() if tag else "<none found>")` for Python 3.x